# if an admin is not logged in Can you filter a ngFor to not show the Admin users.

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I pull a list of users from a database and in the list of users are Admin users and non admin users. I want to display the admin users if an admin is logged in and not display the admin users if no admin is logged in. This is my current code:

```
 <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
                <td>{{user.Salutation.Description === "None" ? "-" : user.Salutation.Description}}</td>
                <td>{{user.FirstName}}</td>
                <td>{{user.Surname}}</td>
                <td>{{user.Region.Description === "None" ? "-" : user.Region.Description}}</td>
                <td>{{user.Institution === null ? "-" : user.Institution}}</td>
                <td>{{user.PrimaryResearchField.Description === "None" ? "-" : user.PrimaryResearchField.Description}}</td>
                <td>{{user.OrcidID === null ? "-" : user.OrcidID}}</td>
                <td>

                  <button title="View" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="viewUser(user.UserKey)">View</button>
                  <button *ngIf="isAdmin || (isSi && userKey == user.UserKey)" title="Edit" class="btn btn-success" (click)="editUser(user.UserKey)">Edit</button>
                  <button *ngIf="isAdmin" title="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteUser(user.UserKey)">Delete</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you edit the post and show your `ts` code ? and the content of `users` if it is possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short and Simple :

```
<ng-template *ngFor="let user of users">
    <tr *ngIf="isAdmin && user.isAdmin"> // check all your conditions here
    .....
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

---

> Another way is :
>
> 1) Filter users array from component side on `ngOnInit` as per the
>   logged in user
>
> 2) Use pipe function to filter the array

Comment: Hi, thanks for your speedy reply, so that will show the admin users does it also show the other users? If an admin user isn't logged in will it only display the non admin users?

Comment: You can madify `*ngIf="isAdmin && user.isAdmin"` as you want it , this is just a demo , how you can do it

Comment: Hi thanks Vivek, I've added the code you suggested making the appropriate changes: `<tr *ngIf="isAdmin && user.role.Description = Admin">` but i get the following error  Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 36 in [isAdmin && user.role.Description = Admin]

Comment: change this line `user.role.Description = Admin` to `user.role.Description === 'Admin'`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Vivek Doshi for the help. I managed to get it to display the correct information with a bit of tweaking. Using a `<ng-template>` didnt work nothing would display in the table so I added the `*ngFor` to the `<tbody>` then I added the following line `<tr *ngIf="isAdmin && (user.TestRole.Description === 'Admin' || user.TestRole.Description === 'Senior Investigators') || user.TestRole.Description === 'Senior Investigators'">`this then loaded all the users if an admin was logged in and the non admin users if an non admin user was logged in.